# Using PRIMARY KEYS in the right way (handling locales)

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `countries` that has the structure: ID, LOCALES_ID, NAME

I want to handle multiple locales with this table, so I need that for different LOCALES_ID, the ID is the same. So, if I insert:

```
INSERT INTO countries (locales_id, name)
VALUES
('1', 'Lorem'),
('2', 'Ipsum');
```

The final result I want on the database is:

```
ID | LOCALES_ID | NAME
1  | 1          | Lorem
1  | 2          | Ipsum
```

But with the INSERT I tried I got the next result:

```
ID | LOCALES_ID | NAME
1  | 1          | Real insert
2  | 2          | Real insert #2
```

My `countries` table has a PRIMAY index on the columns ID and LOCALES_ID and I supposed that this was all what I need for when I insert different locales I get the same ID.

How I can solve this problem?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Why do you want different locales to have the id, makes about as much sense as having different customners with the same customer number. When does ID change, if it's not a unique identifier, what is it?

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson: I want to be ID+LOCALES_ID a unique identifier. I want this because a user selects which is his country, for example 'United States'. If another user is browsing the website with the locale fr_FR (French) I need to show to it 'États-Unis'. With this way, I save always the user.country_id=countries.id and when showing I can do `SELECT u.name, c.name FROM users u LEFT JOIN countries c ON u.country_id=c.id AND c.locales_id='2'`. I need this on multiple parts of the website, so having this how I descrive it it's VERY useful for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to implement here is a one-to-many relationship, i.e. each Country can have multiple Locales. This cannot be achieved with a single table, as you would find yourself with the same Country appearing multiple times. What you should do is split the data in two tables. You can find an example below.

**Structure for Countries table**
- ID int, autoincrement, primary key
- Name varchar

**Structure for Locales table**
- CountryID int, primary key
- LocaleID int, primary key
- Name varchar

Handling INSERT
- To insert in Countries table, simply populate Name field (or any other fields you may need):

```
INSERT INTO Countries
  (Name)
VALUES
  ('Ireland')
```

The ID field will be populated automatically. For this example, we can imagine that "Ireland" will have ID = 1.
- To insert in Locales, you'll pass three values, i.e. CountryID, LocaleID and Name.

```
INSERT INTO Locales
  (CountryID, LocaleID, Name)
VALUES
  (1, 1, 'Lorem')
```

This query will insert LocaleID for the Country with ID = 1 (i.e. Ireland) and 'Lorem' as a name. To insert 'Ipsum', you'll do the same:

```
INSERT INTO Locales
  (CountryID, LocaleID, Name)
VALUES
  (1, 2, 'Ipsum')
```

Where LocaleID will be 2, for Country with ID = 1 and name will be 'Ipsum'.

**How to retrieve the data**
Since now data is split in two tables, you'll have to use a Join to put it together. It's very simple:

```
SELECT
  C.ID AS CountryID
  ,L.Name AS CountryName
  ,L.LocaleID
FROM
  Countries C
  LEFT JOIN
  Locales L ON
    (L.CountryID = C.CountryID) AND
    (L.LocaleID = :InputLocaleID)
```

That's it. Now your query will return the Country with its name in the proper Locale, if it exists. If it doesn't, CountryName and LocaleID will be NULL.

**Update  2012/08/11 - How to use a single table (not recommended)**

If you wish to use a single table for the Countries, you'll have to handle the Country IDs manually. That is, you'll perform an INSERT as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Countries
  (ID, LocaleID, Name)
VALUES
  (:CountryID, :LocaleID, :Name)
```

This, however, will leave you with an issue. Imagine the table contains an unspecified number of Countries and you have to add a new one. What ID would you give to this new Country?

Comment: can you look on my comment at the question? I think I'm not doing a strange table, what I say can be achieved with only a table. Yes, I'll have some duplicated data but I can be done. My locales table are just `ID, LOCALE, NAME` like: `1, en_US, English (US)`. Thank you!

Comment: I understood your requirement. What you're trying to do is using only the Locales table, which can definitely be done, but it's not the best approach for maintainability.  

If you **really** think this is the best design, simply remove the Countries table from above example and add your data to the single table you have.

The key of your issue is that you cannot use any autoincrement field, and you have to pass the whole key when you do an insert. That is, you'll INSERT (ID, LocaleID, Name) passing all three values.

Comment: I updated my answer to better show you how you could handle the single table you have and why it's optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some thing like

```
Locales
(LocalID, LocaleName) Use the standard id e.g. en-GB
Primary Key (LocaleID)
```

Countries (might have to work on this bit for countries like Belgium (Waloon and Flemish)

```
(CountryID,CountryLocaleID)
Primary Key (CountryID)
ForeignKey CountryLocaleID -> Locales(LoacleID)
```

(add any other country specific info, but not the name!

```
CountryTranslations
(CountryID, LocaleID,InternationalisationID) 
Primary Key(CountryID,LocaleID) 
Unique Key(InternationalisatiosnID)
Foreign Key CountryID -> Countries.CountryID
Foreign Key LocaleID -> Locales.LocaleID
Foreign Key InternationalisationID -> Internationalisations.InternationalisationID
```

(This is your link between country and it's name in various Locales

```
Internationalisations
(InternationalsationID, Translation)
PK (InternationalisationID)
```

(All your translations.)